# ¿Por que mi imagen no se muestra?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo dos clases, una aparte que se encarga de dibujar la imagen en una pantalla, y una principal que se encarga de cargar la imagen y llamar el constructor de la clase que dibuja la pantalla.

Clase que dibuja la pantalla:

```
package visorimagenes;

/**
 *
 * @author sshma
 */
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author sshma
 */
public class Pantalla extends JPanel {
    private Image imagen;

    Pantalla(Image img) {
        this.imagen=img;
        System.out.println(imagen);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g); //Para las dimensiones reales de pantalla
        Dimension tam=new Dimension(imagen.getWidth(this), imagen.getHeight(this));
        setPreferredSize(tam);
        setMinimumSize(tam);
        setMaximumSize(tam);
        setSize(tam);
        update(g);


    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(imagen,0,0,this);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

}
```

Clase que pone la imagen:

```
public class VisorImagenes extends JFrame {
    private JScrollPane panel;
    private Pantalla pantalla;

    public VisorImagenes(String archivo)
    {
      super("Visor imagen");
      Image img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(archivo);
      pantalla= new Pantalla(img);
      panel= new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                             JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      getContentPane().add(panel);
      panel.setViewportView(pantalla);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(400,300);
      setVisible(true);

    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        VisorImagenes jaja=new VisorImagenes("hola.jpg");

    }

}
```

El print del constructor Pantalla era para ver si, si estaba pasando la imagen y si la esta pasando, mas no mostrando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de que la imagen se encuentre dentro del paquete **visorimagenes** debes indicarlo en la ruta.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    VisorImagenes jaja=new VisorImagenes("src/visorimagenes/hola.jpg");

}
```

A la hora del trabajo con recursos, como son las imágenes, se utiliza una ruta relativa tomando como referencia el directorio del proyecto. Aunque también se puede utilizar una ruta absoluta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias